# python: instance attribute error

Tags: python

I get a dict to init a class person. there is one field in person: 'name'.  'name' field is optional, meaning that if the dict don't have the 'name' item, then there's no 'name' value of person. I use getter methods to get instance attribute, but it will throw a error if there's no 'name' value. I don't know is there any good programming style to improve my code? Because python create instance field at run time, I don't know how to use getter like java.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,person_dict):
        try:
            self.name = person_dict['name']
        except Exception:
            pass

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

pdict = {}
p = Person(pdict)
print p.getName()
```

AttributeError: Person instance has no attribute 'name'

Comment: As you've already seen in the answers, getters are not 'pythonic', or good python code.  [Here](http://tomayko.com/writings/getters-setters-fuxors)'s a great article on why this is.  To sum the article up: Java always needs getters/setters because without them, refactoring to use them is difficult.  With python, you don't change your interface, as you can use [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self,person_dict):
        self.name = person_dict.get('name')
```

In this case `self.name = person_dict.get('name')` won't raise Exception and Person objects will have `name` attribute (`None` by default)

UPD. Because of `getName` method is useless, I cut it down from example. Access `name` attr directly.

Comment: It's worth noting that 'getter' methods are bad practice in Python - access it directly.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying an answer that notes that is a better one.

Comment: so the better way in python is access attribute directly?

Comment: @remy Yes. The reason to use getters and setters in Java is to leave the class unchanged to code using it if you need to add operations. In Python, we have the [``property()``](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) builtin, so there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,person_dict):
        self.name = person_dict.get('name', 'default_name')

pdict = {}
p = Person(pdict)
print p.name  # there is no need for getter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the exception, then you should make sure the instance has a value for `name`. Since lookup falls back to the class if an attribute can't be found on the instance, an easy way to do this is to simply add `name = None` (or whatever default value you want the instance to use) to the class definition. Assignment to the attribute on the instance will "hide" the default value.

```
class Person:
    name = None
    def __init__(self,person_dict):
        try:
            self.name = person_dict['name']
        except Exception:
            pass
```

You could instead write your `__init__` like this:

```
def __init__(self,person_dict):
    self.name = person_dict.get('name')
```

The `get()` method of dictionaries returns `None` if the key isn't found, or you can provide a second argument with a different default value.